# Export pdf table data and import it into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, import, export

I want to export table data from pdf file and insert it into mysql database. How can I do it?

Regards,
Rekha

Answer (score 1):

Start by converting the PDF into text. There's a program called pdf2text which you could download and use to do that (through `exec` for instance). Alternatively, there are several PHP classes which can convert the PDF into text like [this one](http://sfbrowser.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/web/sfbrowser/connectors/php/class.pdf2text.php) I found for you.

Once you have the text, you'll want to parse the text output and populate the data. You'll most likely want to look at [regular expressions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I have already tried that but it is not suited for converting table data in pdf file.

Comment: The only way to get PDF data into a database will be to read the content of the PDF. No matter what you do, you'll *have* to convert the PDF into text at some point. Is it not working because the text isn't in the proper order (i.e. columns before rows and vice-versa)?

Comment: My pdf file contains table.I have tried but it is not working

Comment: But that doesn't answer my question. Was the table convert into text? Is the table an image? What exactly do you mean by it's not working? If the data is converted to text but in the wrong order, you might still be able to do something with that.

Comment: Yes.I think it is an image. Is there any option to convert it into text

Comment: You'll have to find a library that can extract the image from the PDF. Once you have the image, you'll need to perform OCR on it to convert image to text. If you're on Linux/Unix/OSX, checkout "pdfimages" (part of the poppler-utils, xpdf, or xpdf-utils packages) to extract the images and [Google's ocropus](http://code.google.com/p/ocropus/). Both of those would have to be used using an `exec` call.

Comment: You should also check out [PDF::GetImages](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=PDF-GetImages&mode=module), [PDF::OCR](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=PDF-OCR&mode=module) and [PDF::OCR2](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=PDF-OCR2&mode=module) if you don't mind using Perl instead of PHP.